# VBA to protect and unprotect in given range in sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have applied this macro to protect and unprotect in given range of cells in a sheet here is a problem i am facing in this macro
When I run this macro this macro is protecting in given range of cells A1 to D20 and when I am run again this macro to unprotect in given range it's not unprotecting

```
Sub lockcells()
 Dim Rng
 Dim MyCell
 Set Rng = Range("A1:D20")
 For Each MyCell In Rng
 If MyCell.Value = "" Then
 Else: ActiveSheet.UnProtect Password:="123"
 MyCell.Locked = True
 MyCell.FormulaHidden = False
 ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="123", UserInterFaceOnly:=True
 End If
 Next
End Sub
```

I want to protect and unprotect with single macro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some small adjustment to make it "protect/unprotect".
I made the assumption that you only want to protect/lock a cell if it's **not** empty.

```
Option Explicit

Sub lockcells()
Dim Rng As Range
Dim MyCell As Object

Set Rng = Range("A1:D20") 'Set range to lock cells

If ActiveSheet.ProtectContents = True Then 'Check if sheet is protected
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="123" 'Password to unprotect
Else
For Each MyCell In Rng
    If MyCell.Value <> "" Then 'If cell is empty, if not empty lock the cell
        MyCell.Locked = True 'Lock cell
        MyCell.FormulaHidden = False 'Don't hide formulas
    End If
Next MyCell
ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="123", UserInterFaceOnly:=True 'Protect Sheet
End If
End Sub
```

---

If you want all cells to be editable except a range you can add the following code:

```
'Else
    ActiveSheet.Cells.Locked = False
    ActiveSheet.Cells.FormulaHidden = False
    'For Each MyCell In Rng
```

This will make only `Range("A1:D20")` protected with password. All other cells is free to be editable.

Comment: I have getting run time error after opening workbook again and run the  macro to unprotecting in given range and I have applied these line of code also ```ActiveSheet.Cells.Locked = False
ActiveSheet.Cells.FormulaHidden = False```

Comment: Sorry, my writing mistake, I put it in wrong place when I wrote the code here. The code should have been after `Else`. I've updated my answer. The reason for the error was that we are trying to unlock cells, but the worksheet is locked.

Comment: Thank you so much now it's working perfectly without any error

Answer (score 0):

### Unlock Cells and Hide Their Formulas

- You should consider using `If Not IsEmpty(sCell)` to additionally lock the cells containing formulas (that will be hidden) evaluating to `""`. It makes more sense to me. Think about it.

```vb
Option Explicit

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Locks the non-blank cells in a range and hides their formulas.
' Remarks:      First it unlocks all cells and unhides their formulas.
'               Then, if previously all cells were unlocked, it locks
'               the non-blank cells and hides their formulas.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Sub ToggleLockCells()
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheet1
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = ws.Range("A1:D20")
    
    Dim trg As Range
    Dim sCell As Range
    
    ' Test if no cell is locked.
    If Not IsAnyCellLocked(srg) Then ' no locked cells
        For Each sCell In srg.Cells
            ' 'Blank' ...
            If Len(CStr(sCell.Value)) > 0 Then
            ' ... or 'Empty' to also lock cells with formulas evaluating to ""
            'If Not IsEmpty(sCell) Then '
                Set trg = GetCombinedRange(trg, sCell)
            End If
        Next
    'Else ' at least one cell is locked
    End If
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    If ws.ProtectContents Then
        ws.Unprotect Password:="123"
    End If
    
    ' Unlock the whole range anyway.
    srg.Locked = False
    srg.FormulaHidden = False
    
    If Not trg Is Nothing Then
        trg.FormulaHidden = True
        trg.Locked = True
        MsgBox "Range locked.", vbInformation, "Lock Cells in Range"
    Else
        MsgBox "Range unlocked.", vbExclamation, "Lock Cells in Range"
    End If

SafeExit:
    
    If Not ws.ProtectContents Then
        ws.Protect Password:="123", UserInterFaceOnly:=True
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "Run'time error '" & Err.Number & "': " & Err.Description
    Resume SafeExit
End Sub


''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Checks if at least one of the cells in a range is locked.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function IsAnyCellLocked( _
    ByVal srg As Range) _
As Boolean
    If srg Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    Dim sCell As Range
    For Each sCell In srg.Cells
        If sCell.Locked Then
            IsAnyCellLocked = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next sCell
End Function


''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Creates a reference to the range combined from two ranges.
' Remarks:      An error will occur if 'AddRange' is 'Nothing'
'               or if the ranges are in different worksheets.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function GetCombinedRange( _
    ByVal CombinedRange As Range, _
    ByVal AddRange As Range) _
As Range
    If CombinedRange Is Nothing Then
        Set GetCombinedRange = AddRange
    Else
        Set GetCombinedRange = Union(CombinedRange, AddRange)
    End If
End Function
```