Protect a cell with password in Excel
I'm totally new to VBA in Excel and I want to simply protect a cell with it.
The code can be simple as it can get.
The only thing I want it to do is:

When user inputs correct password it updates to new value.
If user inputs wrong password it asks for correct password.
If user closes the dialog box it reverts the value to the previous one.

Password can be "123" and desired cell can be G6.
I've tried several methods but always got stuck on loops where I could just close the dialog box and the new value would be updated without correct password.
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("G6")) Is Nothing Then
    Dim enteredValue As Variant
    enteredValue = Target.Value ' Store the entered value

    Dim passwordInput As String
    Dim correctPassword As String
    correctPassword = "123" ' Set password

    Do
        passwordInput = InputBox("Enter Password to confirm change (or Cancel to revert):", "Password Required")

        If passwordInput = correctPassword Then ' Correct password, allow the change
            Exit Do
        ElseIf passwordInput = "" Then ' User cancelled
            Application.Undo ' Undo the change immediately
            Exit Do
        End If

    Loop ' Continue if password was wrong

End If

End Sub

Start recording a macro and protect a cell with password. You can then see codes from VBA window.

@BrendonMedeiros Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/69325825/5514747

@BrendonMedeiros https://spreadsheetweb.com/how-to-lock-formula-cells-with-vba/

Ok so I made it to work as intended.
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

' Define password
Const Password As String = "123"

' Check if cell is A1
If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then
    Dim Answer As String
    Answer = InputBox("Input password:", "Password Chack")

    ' Check if answer is ccorrect
    If Amswer = Password Then
        ' allow update
        Exit Sub
    Else
        ' undo update and error message
        Application.EnableEvents = False ' avoid ad infinitum loop
        Application.Undo
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        MsgBox "Inccorect password. Undone", vbCritical, "Error"
    End If
End If

End Sub
